# look and say sequence program not outputting correct sequence

Tags: c

This program is taking input from a file named "input.txt" however it is not outputting the correct look and say sequence. The program should input 21 and 114421. The output should be 1211 and 21241211, however it is just giving me nonsense numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char input[1024];      //The input element
    char result[1024];     //The next element
    int length = 0;        //The length of the input
    int resultLength = 0;  //The length of the result
    FILE *openFile;
    openFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");



    do{
        fgets(input, 1024, openFile);
    } while((input[length++] != '.') && (!feof(openFile)));
    length -= 1; //Decrement length because of the length++ that just executed

    //Go through the loop, adding to the result each time the chain stops

    fclose(openFile);
    char prev = input[0];   //The previous character
    int count = 1;          //The count in the current chain
    int i, j = 0;
    for(i=1; i < length; i++){
        if(input[i] == prev){
            count++;   //If the chain is unbroken, increment the count
        } else{
            //If the chain breaks, store the count and digit in result and reset count
            result[j++] = count + '0';
            result[j++] = prev;
            count = 1;
        }

        //Set prev to be the current digit
        prev = input[i];
    }

    //Handle the last digit using the current value of count and prev
    result[j++] = count + '0';
    result[j++] = prev;

    //Print out the result
    printf("The next element in the sequence is: ");
    resultLength = j;
    for(i=0; i < resultLength; i++){
        printf("%c", result[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    system("pause");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It needs debugging :).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll need to explain more about what the algorithm is.  The line reading loop is weird.  (I think the output is a 1-digit count of the number of the next digit — so 21 maps to 1211 with the first 1 being the count of 2's, the 2 being the digit, the second 1 is the count of 1's, and 1 is the digit.  The 114421 output is consistent with that interpretation. But that is most certainly not instantly clear from your question.)  Interesting edge case: given input `111111111111`, presumably you need `9131` as the output?

Comment: i am not a great C programmer but any help would be great

Comment: `do{
        fgets(input, 1024, openFile);
    } while((input[length++] != '.') && (!feof(openFile)));` is nonsense.

Comment: I always worry when there is no check that the file open correctly. Sure sign that not even basic debug has been tried...

Comment: Shouldn't you change `while((input[length++] != '.') && (!feof(openFile)));` --> `while((!feof(openFile)) && (input[length++] != '.'));` to avoid using the last line of the file twice when end-of-file is reached?

Comment: 1) `length` can not be the input length. 2) `char result[1024];` : `result` must be able to hold twice as long as the input because there is no repeat of the input. 3) Repeat input (and processing) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char input[1024];
    char result[2*sizeof(input)];
    int length = 0;// The length of the input
    FILE *openFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if(!openFile){
        perror("fopen:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fgets(input, 1024, openFile)){
        char *p = strchr(input, '\n');
        if(!p){
            fprintf(stderr, "Input too long!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *p = 0;//chomp newline
        length = p - input;
        if(*input == '.' && !input[1]){
            puts("c u!");
            return 0;
        }
        //conversion
        int resultLength = 0;
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i = j){
            int count = 1;
            for(j = i + 1; input[i] == input[j]; ++j)
                ++count;//Count of repeated characters

            while(count > 9){//Processing when the count exceeds 9 E.g 111111111111 ==> 9131
                result[resultLength++] = '9';
                result[resultLength++] = input[i];
                count -= 9;
            }
            result[resultLength++] = count + '0';
            result[resultLength++] = input[i];
        }
        result[resultLength] = 0;//Add NUL charancter to last for %s of printf

        //Print out the result
        printf("The next element in the sequence is: %s\n", result);
    }
    fclose(openFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/UTqqXL) note : A newline is necessary for each line (also in the last line)

Comment: If you could please add some more comments in the "conversion" part so I could understand more but thank you very much for your help.